# Update column with value from last value until next populated value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which contains an amount per month and a previous month amount.

Each month I need to carry the last previous month amount if it does not exist.

To explain slightly better (and with examples) I might have the following data;

```
Month,Amount,Previous
2019-01-01,100,0
2019-02-01,100,100
2019-03-01,100,null
2019-04-01,100,null
2019-05-01,100,200
2019-06-01,100,null
```

So I want to carry the 100 to March and April and then the 200 to June so it looks like this;

```
Month,Amount,Previous
2019-01-01,100,0
2019-02-01,100,100
2019-03-01,100,100
2019-04-01,100,100
2019-05-01,100,200
2019-06-01,100,200
```

I'm just hitting blanks, I know there is a way but the mind simply isn't putting it together.

I think it's going to involve LEFT JOIN on the same table and getting a MIN month value with the amount where the date is greater than the last month value but is not greater than the next.

Or it's going to be doing a subquery in a WHERE clause and a LEFT JOIN.

So far I've managed the below but it duplicates the May and June rows for each previous value (100 and 200).

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN
        table1 t2 ON
            t1.month > t2.month
```

```
Month,Amount,Previous
2019-01-01,100,0
2019-02-01,100,100
2019-03-01,100,100
2019-04-01,100,100
2019-05-01,100,200
2019-05-01,100,100
2019-06-01,100,200
2019-06-01,100,100
```

Comment: You're joining with *all* the earlier months, not just the immediately preceding month.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(Month date,Amount int,Previous int);
insert into t values
('2019-01-01',100,0),
('2019-02-01',100,100),
('2019-03-01',100,null),
('2019-04-01',100,null),
('2019-05-01',100,200),
('2019-06-01',100,null);

select t.*,
        case when previous is null then
            (select previous from t t1 where t1.month < t.month and t1.previous is not null order by month desc limit 1)
        else previous
        end as previousdownfilled
from t;

+------------+--------+----------+--------------------+
| Month      | Amount | Previous | previousdownfilled |
+------------+--------+----------+--------------------+
| 2019-01-01 |    100 |        0 |                  0 |
| 2019-02-01 |    100 |      100 |                100 |
| 2019-03-01 |    100 |     NULL |                100 |
| 2019-04-01 |    100 |     NULL |                100 |
| 2019-05-01 |    100 |      200 |                200 |
| 2019-06-01 |    100 |     NULL |                200 |
+------------+--------+----------+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

where the case statement checks if things need to be done and the correlated cub query does it. But I suspect this work should be done in the code which creates this table.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, however the t.month in the CASE SELECT cannot resolve to the table in the main query. What version of MySQL did you try this on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) here. In the subquery, we will utilize `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` to get the immediate previous amount value.

```
SELECT
    t1.month, 
    t1.amount, 
    (SELECT t2.amount FROM table1 t2 
     WHERE t2.month < t1.month 
     ORDER BY t2.month DESC LIMIT 1) AS previous 
FROM
    table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySL 8+, you can use window functions.  Unfortunately, MySQL has not (yet) implemented the simplest approach -- `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option.

But you can still do this pretty simply:

```
select month, amount, 
       max(previous) over (partition by grp) as previous
from (select t.*, count(previous) over (order by month) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, I should have added in the original post that I am not using a new version of MySQL, its an older 5.x version, otherwise yeah I believe OVER would be perfect.